# Xvfb-run keyboard detection

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-events, xvfb, xserver

I'm testing xvfb-run possibilities and I display the famous trex game in a chromium tab on a specific DISPLAY with this command line : $

```
xvfb-run -n 1 -f ~/.Xauthority --server-args='-screen 0 1600x1200x24 -shmem -listen tcp' chromium-browser --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --window-size=1600,1200 --window-position=0,0 --kiosk http://www.trex-game.skipser.com
```

The fact is, when I press "space" key, the trex should start walking and jumping. But none of this happen.

So I ran the following command :

```
DISPLAY=:1 xinput
```

And I was surprised to see there was no real keyboards.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Xvfb mouse                                id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Xvfb keyboard                             id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

If I use :

```
DISPLAY=:1 xdotool key space
```

I'm able to jump with the trex, which is normal because xdotool directly interact with the XTEST keyboard if I'm right.

I thought that my X server was listening on the /dev/input folder, but I start wondering if I should somehow attach my keyboard on the x server.

Does anyone know how to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps despite the age of the question.

I don't have the full details, but AFAIK: `Xvfb` is just the Frame Buffer part, Human Interaction Devices (HID) are not included.

> I'm able to jump with the trex, which is normal because xdotool directly interact with the XTEST keyboard if I'm right.

That seems to be correct, my source is this anwser in Unix Stack:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259403

You can try hooking up [X11VNC](https://github.com/LibVNC/x11vnc) to it since the VNC Layer *does* include HID.

Check this post on medium on running X11 apps under containers:

https://sax1johno.medium.com/notes-on-running-gui-applications-in-docker-404a7241c53